# JQUERY mark/stylize if dropdown selection is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I've been using JQUERY DATATABLES and I finally was able to add the "hide column" feature found here:  https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

However instead of using hyperlinks, I am using a button dropdown, as follows:

```
 <div class = "btn-group">      
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
   Hide Column
   <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">Booking</a></li>
     <li><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2">Quote</a></li>
     <li><a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3">Line</a></li>
     ...// and so on
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Here is the JQUERY that links the data-columns to the datatable and hides the column:

```
 var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

 $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
   column.visible(! column.visible());

   ** EDIT **
   $(this).toggleClass("dropSelected");
 });
```

What I would like to do, is when one or more of the dropdown selections have been made (and the column has been hidden) is mark the selected dropdown with a check or change the color of the selection.  This way, the user will immediately know which column has been hidden.

Of course, on the flip side, if the user clicks the link to make the column visible again, the check or color needs to disappear as the column will be visible again.

```
 ** EDIT **
```

Adding CSS to the top of the page:

```
a.toggle-vis.dropSelected {color: red;}
```

Comment: It's superfluous. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks for the heads up - I'll be sure not to thank anyone in advance, but why the downvote???  Is my question not worded properly?

Comment: Beats me, I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @j08691 - This is not a good start to my new account.  I don't suppose you could help me, can you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that all your columns start in visible state, and clicking `a.toggle-vis` changes their visibility, you can simply toggle the class of the element as such:

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
   column.visible(! column.visible());

   this.toggleClass("hidden");
 });
```

And use CSS to cater for how `a.toggle-vis.hidden` is presented

Comment: I'm getting an error on toggleClass . I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Using your answer, I was able to achieve the results I needed (with a few alterations).  Thank you sir.  Any chance I could get an "upvote" on my question???